# Parallax-style scrolling of one non-background image

Tags: css, parallax

This may be hard to explain without a visual but here goes: imagine a 'normal' webpage - nothing fancy. Now imagine a main image sitting just below a header. Imaging this image only showing half of its height in it's container. Now imagine scrolling down the page - as you do so, the main image scrolls in parallax style moving within it's container revealing its other half.

I can't find an example of this, because everything I've found uses background images or other images and elements moving on top of the images. I just want one element (the main image) to appear to have some perspective. Can anyone point me to an example of this?

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve and i think background image is exactly what you should be using. What is the reason behind choosing normal image instead of background-image property in css? No matter what is the reason, you could try putting that image inside overflow: hidden container and manipulate image top/bottom (maybe even padding?) property accordingly, just like in standard parallax effect. I cant find example for it too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't understand why you don't want background images, but in all cases, you can use Parallax.js, which uses the attribute `data-image-src` to specify the image.

Take a look in this demo:

HTML:

```
<div class="demo" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="/path/to/image.jpg"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.demo').parallax({imageSrc: '/path/to/image.jpg'});
```

As seen in: http://pixelcog.com/parallax.js/

Comment: In 2020, arguments against `background-image` in CSS contain, at least, `srcset`, `sizes`, and `loading="lazy"`.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use background image and another div just above of it to show the contents.
you can use bootstrap parallax effect, like look for an example [here](http://www.script-tutorials.com/bootstrap-one-page-template-with-parallax-effect/comment-page-1/)

Answer (score 0):

(I know it is an old topic but I want to explain one possibility to do what OP wants).

I am currently looking for the exact same thing because I want to use the `<picture>` tag to call my images with `srcset` and media query, thus providing different images on different device sizes.
It doesn't look like it is possible though.